# grayed box for enumerate

Tags: color, lyx, enumerate, backgrounds

I am using a lyx article template . I want to put my all enumerate items in grayed box . How can I define the enumerate environment in preamble so that all my enumerated lists appear in a grey boxes. I do not want to use tex code inside lyx document and would like to define this style in preamble itself . Kindly help

Comment: use package `mdframed`

Comment: I want to define it in preamble and do not want to enter any code on document body written in lyx

Comment: Do you allow white space between list items?

Comment: No white spaces pls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

write into the preamble (document->setting->preamble):

```
\usepackage{xcolor,mdframed}
\let\Enumerate\enumerate
\let\endEnumerate\endenumerate
\renewcommand\enumerate{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=black!30]\Enumerate}
\renewcommand\endenumerate{\endEnumerate\end{mdframed}}
```

[image]

for all other options, like rounded corners , frame color, ... read the documentation of `mdframed`